# How to easily review files with ipynb extension on github

Tags: github, ipython, jupyter

Reading the reviews of ipynb files is too hard, so what can you suggest? what is common practice to deal with these kinds of problems? somebody told me to use command-line tools or ipy files but I don't know why what can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub has a feature preview available to diff notebooks in a rich format, but at the time of writing, you cannot add comments to the diff.

[GitNotebooks](https://gitnotebooks.com/) is free and enables notebook reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter Notebook files can be viewed on GitHub website, [Review NB App](https://github.com/marketplace/review-notebook-app) can help with ”reviewing” and discussing notebooks.

[Binder](https://mybinder.org/) can also help with executing them and reproducing environments of Jupyter Notebooks.